# How to make a Plane object on a 3D character always face the camera

Tags: modeling

rn im working on a retro N64/PSX/Dreamcast 3D character model for my fan JJBA Stand ability and I wanted to use a technique where plane objects always face the camera like the bob-ombs on SM64, does anyone knows how to achieve this?
[image]